# Unity 3D: Updating a UI Text at a set rate using numbers from an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a project in unity and I'm writing a script that will display the altitude of my gameobject as it travels. I'm getting its altitude from a text file that I've put into an array. Here's my code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class PlayerController: MonoBehaviour {


 private Vector3 position;
 private double[] nums;
 private double altDisplay;
 public Text altText;        
 void Start()
 {
     //Import text file and read all.
     string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("File.txt");
     if (text != null) 
     {
         //Split the string of text into an array containing each number in the file.
         string[] strings = text.Split (new[] { " ", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

         //Convert each string number to a double.
         nums = new double[strings.Length];
         for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++) 
         {
             nums [i] = Convert.ToDouble (strings [i]);
         }

     }
 }

 void FixedUpdate()
 {

     //Common variables
     int Entries = 6992;
     float speed = 1.0f;

     //Determine the Y altitude
     float yMeters;

     for (int i = 3; i < Entries; i += 7) 
     {
         yMeters = Convert.ToSingle(nums [i + 7] - nums [i]);
         transform.position += transform.up * yMeters * Time.deltaTime * speed;
     }

     for (int i = 3; i < 6999; i += 7) 
     {
         altText.text = (nums[i]).ToString () + "m "; 
     }
 }
```

The reason my for loop starts at 3 and increments by 7 is because my text file has 1000 lines that look like this

> x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x7

and the altitude that I need is the x4 number of each line. My problem is that when I click play, the only altitude that is displayed is the very last one. I understand that the for loop is probably running through each one very quickly, so I guess my question is: How do I get the text to update at the same rate that my gameobject is updating? 
I posted this question on the Unity website a few days ago but haven't gotten an answer yet, so I thought you lovely people might be able to help :)

Comment: Why do you do it in a such a complicated way. If you want to display the altitude of a object you can just assume that 1 unit = 1 meter and just display the objects Y value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to read that values from a text file?

The easy way to do it is:

```
void FixedUpdate{
altText.text = yourGameObject.transform.position.y.ToString();
}
```

You can round that value if you want:

```
altText.text = Mathf.Round(yourGameObject.transform.position.y).ToString();
```

Comment: I'm basing my object off a real-life object in which its path was documented in the form of a text file.